# Strange "debug" error in sass output: @media -sass-debug-info... cluttering css file

Tags: css, netbeans, sass

I've set up a project in netbeans with Sass support. Everything works great except above each rule I get this strange error: `@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/var\/w`

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/var\/www\/html\/hawaii\/wp-content\/plugins\/geqqo\/public\/assets\/scss\/public\.scss}line{font-family:\00003172}}
.geqqo-status a:hover a:active {
  color: #444;
}

@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/var\/www\/html\/hawaii\/wp-content\/plugins\/geqqo\/public\/assets\/scss\/public\.scss}line{font-family:\00003180}}
.geqqo-status footer {
  text-align: right;
}
```

I can't seem to find (googling, etc) what is responsible for this strange reoccurring entry into the output css file.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has a check-button "generate extra information (debug)" which is found in Tools->Options->Misc...when I unchecked that the problem disappeared.